# pycharm shell issue that doesn't occur in terminal

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am currently working on a project that calls the Word2Vec class from gensim. I have downloaded gensim via:

```
pip install -U gensim
```

If I open a python shell and type:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, matutils, interfaces, corpora, models, similarities, summarization
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .word2vec import Word2Vec
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 100, in <module>
    from gensim.models.word2vec_inner import train_sentence_sg, train_sentence_cbow, FAST_VERSION,\
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "__init__.pxd", line 155, in init gensim.models.word2vec_inner (./gensim/models/word2vec_inner.c:9234)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling
```

After uninstalling and reinstalling many scipy, numpy, and gensim variations. And after using the following commands based on what I've read about the above error:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas

easy_install --upgrade numpy

pip install -U gensim
```

Now I get a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gensim import parsing, matutils, interfaces, corpora, models, similarities, summarization
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .word2vec import Word2Vec
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 92, in <module>
    from gensim import utils, matutils  # utility fnc for pickling, common scipy operations etc
ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

If I type:

```
from gensim import utils
```

I get the same error as above. For some reason utils is not being imported properly from gensim but I don't know why this would be happening. I am fairly new to python and this is rather confusing to me but what I've noticed after all the previous installations one BIG FIX!

If I call:

```
from gensim import utils
```

The import utils error **does not occur** when I invoke python2.7 in my terminal. But when I use the python interpreter in pycharm (the following version):

```
2.7.10 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7)

Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
```

The error still occurs.

When I invoke pycharm in my terminal it calls python from the following library:

```
Python 2.7.10 (v2.7.10:15c95b7d81dc, May 23 2015, 09:33:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

I don't know if the python shell in python vs the terminal python shell are different but I don't know why one shell works fine but the other brings up the import utils error. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can check to see if they're the same python with `import sys; print(sys.executable)`.  That being said, for any kind of development, you should consider using a virtualenv and setting up PyCharm to use that as its interpreter.

Comment: thanks they are infact the same python so now I have no idea where the error would be coming from :( @MPlanchard

Comment: It's an odd error. It's definitely related to the PyCharm "pydev" interpreter, but I don't know what could cause the problem. I would try setting up a fresh virtualenv and installing the mentioned packages, setting that as the interpreter in PyCharm, and seeing if you still get the error.